# submitting gridview data to mysql db

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a gridview populated with data which I  need to submit to mysql database. I have done this with vb but do not know how to do it in vb.net.  Can someone please help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the gridview gets populated? Through user input or from database?

Comment: user input. I have a browse and file open system which then populates the gridview. I then want to submit the gridview data to mysql database

Comment: Then you can loop through the grid like this Grid1.Rows[i].Cell[j].Text. Use a foreach loop or for loop.. And save the data.

Comment: In VB.net you have to use () instead of []